# How to Configure Passenger with Apache2 + Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ruby, apache, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I am having trouble installing Passenger on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for Apache2, and was wondering if someone could please help me install Passenger for Apache? I can install Ruby on Rails fine but when I get to the point where I need to install/Configure Passenger it just does not work for me.

If someone could place a list of commands down in the suggestions I would need to install/Configure Passenger. (Keep in mind that I am installing Ruby on Rails via [RVM](https://rvm.io) If that makes a difference.)

I have worked with Ubuntu for the last 3 years and I know a good fair amount about how to get around but this just really stumped me up for the last 3 months.

Hope you can help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link could help you.

**How To Deploy a Rails App with Passenger and Apache on Ubuntu 14.04**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04